# How to handle File names

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, process

I am trying to get the location of an Executable running in memory using `Application.ExecutablePath` and delete it from its current location, however i get the error `The system cannot find the file specified`.

As far as my understanding goes it is because of the space in the path. How do i fix this problem? Here is the relevant code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"cmd.exe /C Del " + Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath);
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Comment: When you have fixed the path you'll probably get a "File In Use" exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to prefer `String.Format` over simple string concats:

```
psi.FileName = string.Format("cmd.exe /C Del \"{0}\"",
                              Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath));
```

Otherwise, I believe this should work as well:

```
psi.FileName = @"cmd.exe /C Del """ + Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath) + """";
```

Comment: The question you asked: _As far as my understanding goes it is because of the space in the path. How do i fix this problem?_ This answers that...

Answer (score 2):

The problem it's not "system cannot find the file specified" if try to run your command in cmd it self you will see that real error it file is acccess denied, but this should works :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe",
"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath);
Application.Exit();
```